# OCMock facebook block mock

Tags: facebook, block, ocmock

I want to mock the facebook login block, but test failed, the block wasn't invoked. Please help me solve the problem.

```
//Test
-(void)testFacebookLogin
{
    id mockManager = OCMClassMock([FBSDKLoginManager class]);
    OCMStub([[mockManager alloc]init]).andReturn(mockManager);
    FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *res = [[FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult alloc]initWithToken:nil isCancelled:YES grantedPermissions:nil declinedPermissions:nil];
    NSError* err = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"This is an error" code:NSURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet userInfo:nil];
    [[mockManager stub]logInWithReadPermissions:OCMOCK_ANY fromViewController:OCMOCK_ANY handler:[OCMArg invokeBlockWithArgs:res,err,nil]];
    __block BOOL invoke;
    [LoginHelper facebookLoginWithLoginResult:^(BOOL success, NSError *error, id result) {
        invoke = YES;
    }];
    XCTAssertTrue(invoke);
}
//LoginHelper.m 
    +(void)facebookLoginWithLoginResult:(LoginResult)loginResult
    {
        UIViewController* currentRootViewController = AppDelegateHelperSingleton.globalDelegate.window.rootViewController;
        FBSDKLoginManager* loginManager = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc]init];
        loginManager.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehaviorNative;
        NSArray* permissions = @[@"email",@"public_profile",@"user_birthday"];
//facebook login with read permisssions
        [loginManager logInWithReadPermissions:permissions fromViewController:currentRootViewController handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error)
        {
            loginResult(result, error);
        }];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
OCMStub([[mockManager alloc]init]).andReturn(mockManager);
```

That's not going to work. The problem you face is that your production code has a dependency which it locks down:

```
FBSDKLoginManager* loginManager = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc]init];
```

In order for your test code to supply a "test double" (something that stands in for the real thing), you need a way to inject it.

There are various approaches to Dependency Injection. You can make it an initializer argument. You can make it a property. If you want the FBSDKLoginManager to be short-lived, you can make it a method argument.

For more, see [How to Use Dependency Injection to Make Your Code Testable](https://qualitycoding.org/dependency-injection/)

Comment: Jon is right, as usual. With OCMock there's a (rather dirty) hack, though, that can be used as a last resort when you don't control the classes. As long as the dependent object is not initialised with a plain init method or the alloc/init can be changed to a `new` then it's possible to stub the `new` method or the alloc/initWith... method to return the mock. See section 9.3. in the reference documentation.